# php + curl cannot set post method

Tags: php, curl

I try to make a post request with php and curl. Here is my code

```
//PHP 5.3.5 and curl: 7.18.2
$ch = curl_init();
if(!empty($save_cookie)){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $save_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $save_cookie);
}else{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/post.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, !$body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    return false;
}

curl_close($ch);
return $postResult;
```

In http://localhost/post.php, I write

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

The result return of curl is always

```
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
```

Comment: Weird.  Can you post a packet trace?  (Use Wireshark or similar.)  Also, is PHP being called via CGI or as a module?  What web server?  See also http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1472.  I suspect that if you were to set POST data and looked at `$_POST` in post.php, you'd see your data.

Comment: I'm using apache + fastcgi. I'm also print $_POST but it' empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option and it will work. Or place it above the `CURLOPT_POST` line.

I think I have encountered this once, when trying to get just the header of a response. Setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

effectively instructs `curl` to issue a `HEAD` request, which is not a `POST` request. I think there is no way to just get the header from a `POST` (and just drop the connection after receiving the header). As a side effect, setting `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to `false` sets the request type to `GET`...

Do you really *need* the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` flag?

Comment: But the problem persists even with FALSE as a third param of 'NOBODY' setopt. And that's a bug, as documentation clearly states that the request type should NOT reset to GET this way.

Comment: @raina77ow you should file a bug report!

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, !$body);`

line right before the

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pars);`

line.

There's an interesting post at the [curl/set_opt page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), shedding some light on this behaviour:

> If your POST data seems to be disappearing (POST data empty, request
>   is being handled by the server as a GET), try rearranging the order of
>   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS setting with CURLOPT_NOBODY. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS has
>   to come AFTER CURLOPT_NOBODY setting because if it comes after it
>   wipes out the header that tells your URL target that the
>   request is a POST not a GET.

Comment: The Content-Type header does not tell anything about `POST` or `GET`.